# What I'm I doing wrong in Dynamic Query

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I am getting **System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: recordId** when running my code. The **oppId** is coming from a flow and the query works if I hardcode an id but not when a variable is referenced.

Here is how I am calling the method

```
Opportunity opp = Database.query(buildQuery('Opportunity', oppId));

private static string buildQuery(String sObjectName, String recordId) {
    List<String> fields = new List<String>(Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    String query  = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM ' + sObjectName + ' where id =:recordId';
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't have `recordId` declared in the scope *where you're actually executing this query*.

Your query filter is literally `' where id =:recordId'` when your query string is returned. `Database.query()` is trying to find that variable and failing (because that's a parameter of your `buildQuery()` method).

To make this work the way you intend, you need to either:

- pass "oppId" as a string literal to your query builder, and change your filter to `' where id =:' + recordId;`
- keep passing the string value of `oppId` (e.g. `006000000000123`) as you are now, and embed it in your filter without trying to do a dynamic variable bind, `' where id = \'' + recordId + '\''`

The first approach will see your query string filter become `' where id =:oppId'`, and `oppId` is in the scope of where `Database.query()` is being called, so it should work.

The second approach will "hardcode" the Id into the query, but it'll still be dynamic insofar as if you pass a different Id to `buildQuery()`, your query string will embed that different Id.

Comment: I think would work, right? `' where id =:oppId'`

Comment: @CasparHarmer That would work, and my first approach would result in that being part of the query string (I edited my answer as you were writing that comment).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I went with option 2